# Why do we close broad questions?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I have been a user of Stack Exchange for a few months, and I know that questions that require a very long answer are closed as "too broad". This seems to be rather conflicting from SE's goal IMO.

> Stack Exchange is a network of 169 communities that are created and run by experts and enthusiasts like you who are passionate about a specific topic. We build libraries of high-quality questions and answers, focused on each community's area of expertise.

Considering this as SE's mission, we would like to make SE a huge database of information to all. Here, I feel that the "too broad" closing gets in the way of posting extremely thorough answers to a question that asks for such. Personally I find SE to be a very easily accessible resource, and it would be great to find detailed answers to questions that would have otherwise been closed as "too broad". Searching for references has always been quite a headache for me, so having crystal clear answers on SE seems to be beneficial to me.

Of course, I did notice that SE also wants **high quality questions** as well, and questions asking for lots of information aren't exactly what you'd call as high quality. This puts me in a dilemma on whether closing "too broad" questions is useful or not.

And of course, you might say, "*We are supposed to discourage people who just ask 'How do I make a computer?' and be on with it*". In such a situation, I really think that human nature can handle it. No one likes to help lazy people. If a overly broad question pops up, it would mostly get ignored for being so. If an asker desperately needs an answer, he may place a bounty on the question. But what I feel is, I don't see any reason to *prevent* someone from answering a broad question.

Please note, I speak from the science sites point of view. I don't know how well my arguments stand for sites like Stack OverFlow or DIY, since I have never used them before.

Comment: How do you figure out which answer to such a question is objectively the best?

Comment: @Oded Isn't that the issue with opinionated questions? I don't think all broad questions always have opinions in them.

Comment: Fair enough. But "Too Broad" tends to mean to me - "A good answer will fill a book". I don't know what you consider "Too Broad" to mean.

Comment: @Oded Ahh, it's rather subjective isn't it then? What's broad for one may seem well within limits to another.

Comment: Sure, it is subjective. But the main criteria - is it something that can be *reasonably* answered in a few paragraphs? If not - it is likely too broad.

Comment: The type of broad questions that I prefer not getting closed would be like, "Can you explain this concept [insert-concept here] to me?". Arguably a few others would also have suvh questions, and they can get benefitted.

Comment: I wouldn't call those "Too Broad". "Explain to me" falls under - "Not clear what you are asking", usually - because the OP needs to clarify *what* they don't understand in the concept. It can sometimes be "Too Broad" - depending on the concept (say TCP/IP - too broad... Dependency Injection - need to know what's needs explaining).

Comment: @Oded Does [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112251/which-predictions-of-the-force-awakens-darths-droids-bingo-were-correct/112253#112253) answer on ScifiSE classify as a broad answer and subsequently as a broad question by the asker too. Or do different sites have different *tolerance levels* to the extent of broadness?

Comment: This is definitely something different sites will decide for themselves (and frankly, these are long, but not *book length*).

Comment: @Oded Ahh, alright then. So something that's excessively long would be closed as broad right? But frankly, why do we need to close them anyway? They will be ignored by many for demanding too much right? If someone does decide to sit down and write, why prevent him from doing so? Even if he doesn't explain completely, but gives a link to a pdf or any other big source, it's still a win-win right? SE gets a very huge resource directly linked to SE, making it easily accessible than ever, to all future users who would need help in the same manner as the OP. Isn't this so?

Comment: A bunch of questions like these can become popular. And then people think they are the kind of question that is to be encouraged. We need to close them so we don't encourage more of them. Giving a link is bad - ever hear about [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)? If that happens, the answer becomes useless.

Comment: @Oded A link rot seems like a bad things indeed. I did explain the "do not encourage these" in the body of the question. Is it perhaps that I was inadequate in my explanation?

Answer (score 10):

> In such a situation, I really think that human nature can handle it. No one likes to help lazy people. If a overly broad question pops up, it would mostly get ignored for being so.

Sometimes, humans work like this, but often enough they don’t.
Instead they will do things like:

- Pick an aspect of the broad topic and write a partial answer about it. While SE accepts partial answers, there is a problem if there are too many of them.
- Link to their favourite book or other resource on the subject, which has all the problem of link-only answers.
- Write an overly simplifying summary.
- Write an answer to tell you where you can best study this subject.

And if all of this weren’t already bad on its own, if somebody comes along and manages to cram an actual answer to this question within the character limit, nobody (except the asker) will want to read it and evaluate it.
This does not only mean that errors and other problems will not be corrected or criticised, nobody will vote on the answer either, which in turn leads to disappointment (in particular if other answers get upvoted).
And that’s not even taking into account the problem that answers to such questions cannot be treated as one entity while voting anymore: If three chapters of the answer are excellent and one chapter is bad, how should you vote? And how does this compare to the other answer, where the chapter on another topic is the bad one?

Finally, let’s not forget that if people do not answer the question, we still have a disappointed asker. That will also happen if we close the question, but then we are at least telling the asker what is wrong (after all, they may not realise that their problem is as big as it is).

Comment: "*While SE accepts partial answers*" What?!? If there are many answers, each partial, and all together makes a complete answer, which one do you mark as accepted?

Comment: @Unitato: For normal questions, it may happen, e.g., that answering one part actually solves the problem while the other part is unanswerable altogether. However, for too broad questions what you’re describing is one of the problems.

Answer (score 4):

> If a overly broad question pops up, it would mostly get ignored for being so.

Let's assume that this is the case and, as a thought experiment, consider a Stack Exchange site where community consensus was that even overly broad questions should not be closed (just ignored instead).

I think the inevitable outcome would be a rise in the number of unanswered questions, and that particular SE site becoming just another Q&A site, where  people come looking for answers and find many unanswered questions instead.

Coming back to the Stack Exchange network as it is currently designed, the reason we close broad questions is because good questions with good answers, are much more helpful to people who are looking for answers.

We should all work to improve broad questions, and we have the mechanism to do that which is the 5 day On Hold period applied to every question when 5 experienced users or one moderator agrees to close.

Answer (score -11):

I think you are right in many cases.

I've seen a lot of questions already what could have been answered, but they were closed as 'too broad'.

It seems, the "community" simply won't understand that such "too broad" questions could be answered, but they simply don't require the detailedness as usual. They need a synthetical answer, not a detailed one as usual.

I think it is a structural problem of the SE, although not the largest one.

The easy workaround for the OPs to delete the question, wait a little bit, and later ask multiple ones with narrowed down topic.

Unfortunately, most of the newbies don't bother with the sites enough to understand it, thus they simply leave. With them, all the content they could have produced, is lost.

Comment: If it could be broken down into smaller pieces that are each an entire question, clearly **1.** the original *was* too broad by definition, and **2.** they should have done that in the first place, with far greater benefit for themselves and other users. It's not a case of "the community" not understanding, it's that we don't write books here, and the majority of users do understand that very well.

Comment: @Nij You simply won't understand that such questions don't require a book long answer. They require only a summary of this "book". Just as the whole community.

Comment: I don't understand that an entire book is not needed, and yet there are literal books written to answer just small parts of many questions closed as too broad. Sure...

Comment: @Nij It is true, but I think the OP wants in these cases not the whole book, he wants exactly a quick summary. If he would want a book, he would visit the amazon.com and not the stackexchange.

Comment: @Nij I only tried to explain, that any long answer could be summarized to a short one. It wouldn't be a "book summary", it would be a not detailed answer to a not specific question. The OP would get what he wants (likely if he would want a detailed answer, then he would ask a detailed question), the answerer would get the rep (if their answer is good), and so is it. Most of the "too broad" questions would be pretty well answerable, that is all.